# Cron expression using NCrontab for daily run starting at any given time with 50 minute interval

Tags: c#, cron, .net-core-3.1

I need to run a task every 50 minutes interval between given start and end datetime every day.
For example the interval would be like starting midnight at 00:00, 00:50, 01:40, 02:30, 03:20.

I have tried with the below code but it is not giving the expected datetime with 50 minutes interval.

```
        //NCronTab to schedule task with 50 minutes interval
        int time = 50;
        DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime endDateTime = startDateTime.AddHours(6);

        var parseOptions = new CrontabSchedule.ParseOptions(){IncludingSeconds = true};
        var schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse($"0 */{time} * * * *", parseOptions);

        Console.WriteLine($"Start at: {startDateTime}");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"********************"}");

        foreach (var d in schedule.GetNextOccurrences(startDateTime, endDateTime))
        {
            //Get the next occurrences
            Console.WriteLine($"{d}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{"********************"}");
```

Example outcome:

Start at: 05/30/2020 14:29:43

---

05/30/2020 14:50:00

05/30/2020 15:00:00

05/30/2020 15:50:00

05/30/2020 16:00:00

05/30/2020 16:50:00

05/30/2020 17:00:00

05/30/2020 17:50:00

05/30/2020 18:00:00

05/30/2020 18:50:00

05/30/2020 19:00:00

05/30/2020 19:50:00

05/30/2020 20:00:00

---

Can anybody please help me to get know what is missing in the Cron expression? Any other approaches are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Quartz engine, use below cron expression to run task every 50 min.

cron expression - 0 0/50 0 ? * * *

here 0/50 - task starts at 0 min. If you have to start from 1 min then - 0 1/50 0 ? * * *

Hope, it answers your question.